# How exactly does activating CLEAR cause an asynchronous modulus 12 counter to reset?

Tags: counter, ripple-counter

I'm confused about how Clear manages to reset the counter. The trigger is falling edge.

Starting from where the counter is in the image (I'll refer to each JK flip-flop as F1 etc.):

1. At first, we have F1 Q = 1, F2 Q = 1, F3 Q = 0, F4 Q = 1.
2. For a split second, after falling edge trigger: F1 Q = 0, F2 Q = 0, F3 Q = 1, F4 Q = 1.
3. Because F3 and F4 both emit 1, Clear is activated by a HIGH input - the thing is, F1 Q is **already** 0 (so there is no falling edge trigger effect) and I don't understand how Clear affects F3 and F4.

How is it possible that F3 Q and F4 Q become 0, and therefore we end up with the counter restarting at F1 Q = 0, F2 Q = 0, F3 Q = 0, F4 Q = 0?

[image: The circuit in question]

Comment: Is the clear input a synchronous or asynchronous input? If it is asynchronous, the clock isn’t required as the input is level sensitive.

Comment: Please label all of the relevant signals in your schematic.

Comment: @Kartman - The Clear input is asynchronous. I understand how the asynchronous input works and why the Q output would be 0, at least for the LSB flip-flop (F1)...but I don't understand how *all* the flip-flops are reset.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Updated with labels!

Comment: All the flip-flops are reset because the clear signal goes to the reset input of all of them. Those connections labelled "0" are reset inputs.

Comment: @Finbarr - That's literally all I was missing. I don't know why I had such tunnel vision that I didn't see that myself. Curse my brain. (Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the flip-flops are set to 0 (reset) by the application of a logic HI to the reset input (labelled 0) of each flip-flop - not a falling edge. As long as the Selector line is low this cannot happen. When the selector line is HI, as soon as both F3 and F4 go high, all 4 FFs are reset.

If only F3 and F4 were connected to the Clear gate, it would be theoretically possible for F1 to be high and not affected by the reset pulse. This is unlikely to occur during "normal" operation, but for instance it might occur on power-on. Or, if for some reason the Selector line were not always high and were applied when the counter were at (let's say) a hex value of D, the same result would occur.

Also note that the Preset line (input "1" at each FF) works much like the preset line, except that it sets the FF LOW rather than HIGH. And yes, if you set both the 0 and 1 inputs to a HIGH condition simultaneously, Bad Things happen - so it's important not to do it. In effect, this means that if the Select line is HIGH, the Preset line should be LOW.